# Little question about finding a MacLaurin expansion for $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, derivatives

First off all, I am sorry if my english is not perfect. 
I need help again for this exercise:

Find Maclaurin series expansion for $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x}$.

That's what I did:

$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x}=\frac{x^2+1-1}{1-x}=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1-x}= -x-1+\frac{1}{1-x}$.

I know that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1 $. 
But What to do with $-x-1$?

$(-x-1)'=-1$ and $ (-x-1)''=0$.

If I chose to find the *n*th derivative for $f(x)$:

$f'(x)=-1+(1-x)^{-2}$

$f''(x)=0+(-2)(1-x)^{-3}(-1)=(-1)^22!(1-x)^{-3}$

$...................................................$

$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{2n}(1-x)^{-(n+1)}n! \Rightarrow f^{(n)}(0)=n! \Rightarrow f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$

It's this correct? I am a little confused and I hope someone could help me again..

Comment: I am a little disappointed: Very recently, you asked a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57574) of a similar nature.  I answered, stressing the importance of recycling known expansions, in particular the expansion of $1/(1-z)$.  The answer stressed the usefulness of avoiding derivative calculations if possible. This answer was accepted, and yet a day later you are attacking a very similar, indeed easier, problem by repeated differentiation.

Comment: If you didn't understand @André's (wonderful and applicable) answer to your previous question, you should not have accepted so quickly. Accept answers only when you have digested them fully and are fully satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you know $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$.  What happens if you multiply both sides by $x^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Think about it for a minute - $-x-1$ is **already** an infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$; in this case, $a_0 = -1$ and $a_1 = -1$ and $a_n=0$ for $n>1$.

(The fact that the series is McLaurin lies in that we are seeking a series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$; for other Taylor expansions we want a series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$ for some $a$).